# Wifi freezes on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, intel-wireless

My wifi freezes randomly on Ubuntu 16.04. It recovers either on reconnect or by restarting the iwlwifi, i.e.

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Depending on the position of starts it might freeze again after a random period from a couple of seconds to hours.

```
sudo dmesg | grep wifi
```

gives

```
[   11.998788] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   12.138269] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[   12.158953] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: base HW address: 5c:e0:c5:40:7e:d2
[   15.407862] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
[  336.819378] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[  336.845631] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[  336.872297] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: base HW address: 5c:e0:c5:40:7e:d2
[  336.943626] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 1101.338499] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'wd_disable' ignored
[ 1101.341003] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[ 1101.359871] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[ 1101.384760] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: base HW address: 5c:e0:c5:40:7e:d2
[ 1101.453981] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
```

I tried to track `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/syslog` to see if a specific message is printed before freezing however nothing was printed related to wifi. I disabled Ipv6 for my wifi connection. I also modified my `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` so now it looks like

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
options iwlwifi wd_disable=1
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

with various combinations of the last 3 lines commented.

Hardware: HP Envy m6 laptop
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

UPD: The problem disappears when I turn off the bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

If this problem disappears after you disable bluetooth, I think this can be solved by turning of bluetooth coexistence.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

and reboot.

Comment: BTW I was struggling with dropped packets on my Atheros device for a long time. It appeared that I enabled BT_COEX myself there. It is off by default on Atheos and on on Intel.